# How to split MUI v5 theme into separate files by theme options?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a very big MUI v5 theme with around 800 lines (including TypeScript type augmentation). Something like this:

```
let myTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      // lots of custom props
    },
    secondary: {
      // lots of custom props
    },
  },

  typography: {
    // lots of custom variants
  },
});
```

I'd like to split this huge file into separate files by theme props. Like this:

- palette.ts
- typography.ts
- ...etc.

Then in **theme.ts** create a theme based on these files. How can I do that? And how to manage TypeScript type augmentation in this case (where to keep type augmentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't fully expand the theme code and theme props but I usually build out my themes from a directory called `theme` and my `createTheme` is within an *index.js* file:

### primary

*primary.ts* with it's logic

```
const primary = {
  // lots of custom props
}

export default primary
```

### secondary

*secondary.ts* with it's logic

```
const secondary = {
  // lots of custom props
}

export default secondary
```

### typography

*typography.ts* with it's logic

```
const typography = {
  // lots of custom props
}

export default typography
```

### theme

bring in the files and add them:

```
import primary from './primary.ts'
import secondary from './secondary.ts'
import typography from './typography.ts'

const myTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary,
    secondary
  },
  typography
});
```